# Download post as text file

Tags: 7, nodes, importing-exporting

I wanted to provide functionality in which where user decides to cancel his account, he can download all the post that he has created as txt file. Is there any drupal module that helps to achieve this, or at-least that allows to export node as txt file in Drupal 7.

I have gone through [Print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module, but it does not support txt file and I can not use PDF option, as this will take long time to generate PDF of all usaer created node upon cancellation of account.

Please suggest how can I proceed.

-- Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the [views_data_export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) ....  it can export to CSV or basic text format. and you could select a users Nodes: title and body at least ... and any other fields you want...

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of
>   data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered
>   progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support
>   exporting in the following types:
>
> CSV
>
> Microsoft XLS
>
> Microsoft DOC
>
> Basic TXT
>
> XML

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I don't have view for that, I wanted to perform this action in background and just give users the option to download the file. Is this possible?

Comment: you make a view with a contextual view for a users node, or a filter for a users nodes. you give them a link and they get a button that says DOWNLOAD TXT FILE. It uses the BatchAPI to stream a file to them ........... you have to give them a link and send the file to them. This does that.